# SVG tooltip disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip, getuikit

I've got a map with several regions and want to show a tooltip with its name when hovering over it.

The tooltip will display but disappears immediately. It doesn't matter where I put the tooltip (g, a or polygon), but I believe the g-node is the right place.

Example with three circles:

https://codepen.io/suntrop/pen/BmLZzN

```
<svg width="246px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 246 64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 47.1 (45422) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g class="testtooltip" title="My Tooltip" id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <circle id="Oval" fill="#D8D8D8" cx="32" cy="32" r="32"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="testtooltip" title="Will Show" id="Page-2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <circle id="Oval" fill="#B8E986" cx="123" cy="32" r="32"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="testtooltip" title="And Hide" id="Page-3" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <circle id="Oval" fill="#D8D8D8" cx="214" cy="32" r="32"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The JS

```
$(function() {
        UIkit.tooltip('.testtooltip').show();
});
```

When I use the tooltip on a P or IMG element the tooltip stays while hovering the element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like UIkit doesn't support tooltips on SVG elements. To decide whether an open tooltip should remain open, UIkit regularly calls an `isVisible()` function which in turn reads the target element's `offsetHeight`. SVG elements don't have an `offsetHeight`: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784

Thus, UIkit thinks the element is hidden and immediately hides the tooltip too.